# Intent Extras of GCMIntentService is not passed

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-manifest

I coded `GCMIntentService` but called `Activity` cannot get the Extras.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        resultIntent.putExtra("PushType", "test"); // Put String Extra.

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

and called `MainActivity` is coded as below.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    final Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

    if (receivedIntent != null && receivedIntent.hasExtra("PushType")) {
            // Breakpoint at here. but no Extras are given.
        }       
    }
}
```

I made breakpoint at the `receivedIntent` and `mExtras` inside of it shows null.

Additionally, my called `MainActivity` manifest is coded as below.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I changed called intent to another `Activity` and it successfully loads Extras.
The manifest of substitute activity (which successfully contains Extras) was as below.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".NotificationActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to override onNewIntent(Intent intent) method and inside onNewIntent() call setIntent(intent).  Then onResume() will pick up the new intent.  See [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) for more detail.

Comment: I would highlight the use of 'PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT' in onMessage() as without it, the existing Intent is passed to onNewIntent() and it had this newbie confused for some time.