# Send intent from GcmIntentService to the current activity without starting the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

How can I send an Intent from `GcmItentService` to the Activity that is open right now. I need data from push notification before I can update the list in the Activity. What I don't want is calling startActivity(Intent) (because obviously the activity is already open). Also, onResume method does not get called when the activity is still open. Lets say I have a String that I want to send to the current Activity, what can I do to achieve that?

I have already done what is stated in this thread:
[Intent Extras of GCMIntentService is not passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061190/intent-extras-of-gcmintentservice-is-not-passed)
, but I couldn't get it to work. A simple step by step instruction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may simply use LocalBroadcastManager.

> Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects
>   within your process. This is has a number of advantages over sending
>   global broadcasts with sendBroadcast(Intent):
>
> - You know that the data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so
>     don't need to worry about leaking private data.
> - It is not possible for
>     other applications to send these broadcasts to your app, so you don't
>     need to worry about having security holes they can exploit.
> - It is more
>     efficient than sending a global broadcast through the system.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_ACTION_NAME);
intent.putExtra("PushType", "test");            
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Write a receiver in your activity that handles action "YOUR_ACTION_NAME"

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            messageReceiver, new IntentFilter("YOUR_ACTION_NAME"));
}


private BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
};
```

For more detail: [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Comment: Looks good. I will try this tomorrow and accept your answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted.